# Can i convert math.js object into JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, math, derivative, math.js

I'm developing simple js neural network and need to create javascript function (derivative of entered by user) before learning starts.

I know about evaluate(), but i think it'll be slowly than simple function.

That is what i want:

```
const derivative = math.derivative('x^2/sin(2x)', 'x');
const derivative_func = derivative.please_stay_func();
...
while(1) alert(derivate_func(12)) //:) alert result of (2 * 12 * Math.sin(2*12) - 2 * Math.pow(12, 2) * Math.cos(2*12)) / Math.pow(sin(2*12), 2)
```

Is it real? And maybe i'm not right about speed. Maybe there is some better ways - write here.

Comment: Sorry but... is what real? - _"Maybe there is some better ways - write here"_ what do you mean by better?

Comment: @evolutionxbox another lib

Comment: I don't think that answers the comment?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i need decision for math.js or another better way to create f'() js function from f() written by user. Or tell me why it's not real

Comment: your `please_stay_func` is called `compile`: `fn = math.derivative('...').compile()`

Comment: Not every programmer know how do math bro XD, but sure we can simplify everything and make helper function out of it

Comment: @georg but it also need evaluate, it's not clear js function

Comment: @shumik_UA: right, make a wrapper then: `d = math.derivative('...').compile(); fn = d.evaluate.bind(d)`

Comment: @georg this is just call evaluate by fn, isn't it?

Comment: @shumik_UA: yes, but that's different from the global `math.evaluate` - it executes an already compiled function, no parsing involved.

Answer (score 1):

i am on mobile, please edit this

maybe this is want you want to do

```
const countThings = (customValue) ==>{
let x = 'x^2/sin(x)';
let y = 'x';
 x = math.parse(x)
y = math.parse(y)
return math.derivative(x, y).evaluate({x:customValue});}

console.log(countThings(12))
```

and don't do while(1) alert because it will keep alerting

Comment: Not exactly. I want to count f' result without evaluate, by creating ready js functionfrom math.js object

Comment: and where is the please_stay_func come from ?

Comment: you want set the x and y by input?

Comment: I use "Function('"use strict"; STR_TO_FUNC')();" To convert user text to another function and it works correctly. So i need something like this, but with derivative: user text -> math.js object -> derivative function (math.js object) -> javascript function. All stages are done except last.

Comment: maybe you can show us your function in the question.

Comment: It's custom function. User write text, it converts to math.js and it finds derivative. All works good. I just need to make function that don't need math.js and will count result of derivative func which is made by math.js